# ComboBox Visual Studio Csharp

Tags: c#, combobox

Estou complementando um sistema com duas `combobox`

Na `comboBox1` deverá aparecer o nome das pastas para a seleção do usuário, 
Na `comboBox2` deverá aparecer os `.exe` que serão transferidos para um diretório após clicar em um `button` para copiar o arquivo selecionado na `combobox`.

Procurei em alguns tutoriais pela internet, porém não achei nenhum desta forma.

Alguém tem alguma dica??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Como popular os combobox:**

```
private void FillCombo()
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\temp");
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test2", "*.exe");

    foreach (var t in dirs)
    {
        cmbDir.Items.Add(t);
    }

    foreach (var t in files)
    {
        cmbArq.Items.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Para copiar os arquivos:

```
File.Copy("arquivoOrigem", "arquivoDestino");
```

Não esqueça do `using System.IO;`

Agora se você quiser selecionar mais de um arquivo você pode usar o checkedListBox ou ListView. O procedimento é o mesmo.

Comment: Entendi a lógica, é até bem simples. Porém estou tendo dificuldades no cmb, onde retorna o erro de que ele não existe no contexto atual.

Comment: Você precisa renomar o cmbDir e cmbArq pro nome dos combobox que voce tem na sua aplicação

Comment: funcionou meu amigo
muito obrigado